# How to install Google Cloud bigquery to python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm very new to python just for context.

I'm trying to download Google Cloud Bigquery to Python, but I'm running into errors.

I'm following directions from here: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/
Which essentially is telling me to download it using the following:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
<your-env>\Scripts\activate
<your-env>\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-bigquery
```

I copied and pasted this in my anaconda prompt. I was able to run only the first line of code (`pip install virtualenv`)

The second and the third says "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

[image]

Comment: `pip install google-cloud-bigquery**` try this

Answer (score 0):

In this context `<your-env>` is a placeholder for the name you want to assign to the new virtual environment. Try:

```
virtualenv myenv
myenv\Scripts\activate
```